# Docker fails to listen on port XXXX in Azure

Tags: azure, docker, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I can't load a container and listen on the designated port with an Azure App Service. I am using a B2 App service plan - Linux - App Services. I have done the following:

- Designed the port
- Designated the container port
- Reviewed the Docker configuration (user/pass/container reg)
- Delayed the Docker wait to 300 seconds
- Used a minimal 'Hello World!' api

Additionally, I have included all of the details associated with this deployment. I am entirely stumped and have no idea what could be going on.

Azure Config:

```
  {
    "name": "Port",
    "value": "5001",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_RETENTION_DAYS",
    "value": "21",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITED_PORT",
    "value": "5001",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT",
    "value": "300",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE",
    "value": "false",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
```

Basic dotnet core 6 app:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
 
}

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Simple Docker container:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5005
EXPOSE 5001

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerDeployApp/DockerDeployApp.csproj", "DockerDeployApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DockerDeployApp/DockerDeployApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerDeployApp"
RUN dotnet build "DockerDeployApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerDeployApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerDeployApp.dll"]
```

Logs:

```
2022-04-13T22:00:16.487Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 5001:5001 --name minimalapitest_0_785788dd -e Port=5001 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=minimalapitest -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=minimalapitest.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=723a5e2d371f6deba79eab8b7c111520c7ef9bd6c79c5131aeeacb774e89c15e -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 myAcr.azurecr.io/api:test01
2022-04-13T22:00:22.116Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container minimalapitest_0_785788dd for site minimalapitest
2022-04-13T22:00:22.152Z ERROR - Container minimalapitest_0_785788dd for site minimalapitest has exited, failing site start
2022-04-13T22:00:22.155Z ERROR - Container minimalapitest_0_785788dd didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 5001, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2022-04-13T22:00:22.177Z INFO  - Stopping site minimalapitest because it failed during startup.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Azure config file, change **WEBSITED_PORT** to **WEBSITES_PORT**.

In your Docker file, remove **EXPOSE 5005**.

Comment: The error below keeps popping up after my changes. I tried what you mentioned and it it resulted in this error: 2022-04-14T17:41:52.056655149Z standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error